# Bollinger Bands indicator in R

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am currently trying to write a simple strategy using Bollinger Bands in `R`. The goal is to enter a long position when the closing price touches the lower band and exit when it touches the upper one. To do that I firstly wrote two simple function to use as indicators:

```
BBandsDown <- function(HLC,n=20,maType,sd=2){
               bbdown <- BBands(HLC,n,maType,sd)$dn
               colnames(bbdown)<-"bbdown"
               return(bbdown)
               }

BBandsUp <- function(HLC,n=20,maType,sd=2){
             bbup <- BBands(HLC,n,maType,sd)$up
             colnames(bbup)<-"bbup"
             return(bbup)
             }
```

Then I added the indicators

```
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'Cl',
          arguments = list(x=quote(mktdata)),
          label = 'close')


add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'BBandsDown',
          arguments = list(HLC = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=10,maType="SMA",sd=1.5),
          label = 'bbandsdown1.5')

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'BBandsUp',
          arguments = list(HLC = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=10,maType="SMA",sd=1.5),
          label = 'bbandsup1.5')
```

Then I define Signals and Rules. My problem is that I cannot use the `applyStrategy` command because it reply.

```
 Error in BBands(HLC, n, maType, sd) (from strategy_bbands.r!15334IYx#2) : 
 Price series must be either High-Low-Close, or Close/univariate.
```

I tried with both `HLC = quote(Cl(mktdata))` and `HLC = quote(HLC(mktdata))` but the error is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a reproducible example.

The error is pretty clear that you're passing in the wrong data.

I suspect that you have mangled the data prior to calling `applyStrategy` , but there isn't enough here to validate that.

See the `bbands.R` demo in the demos directory for a working example.